# Job scheduler in android nougat is not running

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler, android-7.1-nougat

I am trying to make job scheduler run after every 3 seconds but it doesnt work on android noughat. Here is my code.

```
     mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );
     JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder( 1,
                            new ComponentName( getPackageName(), JobSchedulerService.class.getName() ) );


                  builder.setPeriodic(3000);
                    builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
                    builder.setPersisted(true);
                    JobInfo j=builder.build();
                    mJobScheduler.schedule(j);
```

Job Scheduling service that contains the code to be executed on jobs.

```
       public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {

        private Handler mJobHandler = new Handler( new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage( Message msg ) {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "JobService task running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                jobFinished( (JobParameters) msg.obj, false );
                return true;
            }
        } );

        @Override
        public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params ) {
        //    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "kutta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            mJobHandler.sendMessage( Message.obtain( mJobHandler, 1, params ) );
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onStopJob( JobParameters params ) {
            mJobHandler.removeMessages( 1 );
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Most likely, there is a minimum period of a minute. `AlarmManager` has such a limit.

Comment: No, the problem is tht it works on android marshmallow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum period a job can be scheduled is 15 minutes. This started with Nougat. If it is set to a value less than 15 minutes, the job will use 15 minutes.

[MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS](http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#80)

[getMinPeriodMillis()](http://androidxref.com/7.1.2_r36/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#85) copy & paste of function description below

> Query the minimum interval allowed for periodic scheduled jobs.  Attempting to declare a smaller period that this when scheduling a job will result in a job that is still periodic, but will run with this effective period.

Comment: But does this limitation also apply to firebase job dispatcher

Comment: The firebase job dispatcher does not use that limitation because its uses the scheduling component in Google Play services. I'm not familiar with the scheduling limitations in Google Play services. A new question specific for the firebase job dispatcher might get you an answer or some experimentation with that library.